# Magento: I want my bundled product report

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product, reports

It includes the product name and quantity as well as it will display the report on corresponding day how much product ordered. Actually i am selling food product daywise weekly bundled product. Please help me to get custom report in magento i am new here.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Please be more specific: Did you try using the "Sales Report" feature in the Magento admin? What are you missing there? "i am selling food product daywise weekly bundled product." seems to indicate some special case for your site, but I don't understand it.